# Describing elements in a principal ideal in a ring that does not have a $1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be any ring that does not contain $1$. For $a\in R$, describe the elements of $(a)$.

Breaking this down piece by piece. Since the ring $R$ does not contain $1$, then the ring does not contain an identity element. Therefore, to describe the principal ideal $(a)$, how should I approach the problem or what should I think about? Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Well, it has to contain all sums and differences of elements in the ideal, and it must contain all elements of the form $rx$, $xs$, and $rxs$ withere $x\in I$, and $r,s\in R$. And sums of these. And differences of these. What do sums and differences of such elements look like? What happens when you multiply such a sum or difference by elements of $R$, on either side?

Comment: If $R$ does not have a unit, is $(a)$ defined as the smallest ideal containing $a$ ?

Comment: @CaptainLama: Yes; in general, $(X)$ is the smallest ideal that contains $X$.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest ideal that contains $a$ must contain:

1. $a$, $-a$, $a+a$, $-(a+a)$, etc. That is, the additive cyclic subgroup of $R$ generated by $a$. This is the set $\{na\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.
2. All elements of the form $ra$ with $r\in R$. Note that this is already closed under sums and differences, since $ra-sa = (r-s)a$.
3. All elements of the form $as$ with $s\in R$. This is also closed under sums and differences.
4. All elements of the form $ras$ with $r,s\in R$. This is **not** closed under sums and differences, so you also need sums and differences of such elements.
5. Sums of elements of each of the previous forms.

That means that, at the very least, $(a)$ must contain all elements of the form
$$ na + ra + as + \sum_{i=1}^m r_ias_i$$
where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $r,s,r_i,s_i\in R$, $m\geq 0$.

Now the question is: does it contain any more elements, or do these elements already suffice to give you an ideal?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Arturo. But, I am still confused honestly.

Comment: @Ryan: Well, since all you say is you are confused, I can’t help. Now, if you try thinking through what I wrote and you manage to figure out *where* you are confused and *why*, and actually say it out loud, then maybe I or someone else will be able to help.

Comment: @Ryan: It’s okay to be confused, but just saying “I’m confused” doesn’t allow anyone to help you clear up the confusions. Neither does accepting an answer you don’t understand just because you don’t want to say what it is you are confused about.

Comment: I am still thinking through it and will post my questions here shortly. At the moment, I am trying to digest the entire response you've posted so I am confused about it entirely. For instance, after you have written the summation of all the elements that (a) must contain and ask if it contains any more elements, I am trying best to understand if it does or does not since $r$ and $s$ is closed under the sums  and differences. Moreover, since the additive cyclic subgroup of $R$ generated by $(a)$ is given by the set such that $\{na | n\in\mathbb{Z}$... cont..

Comment: And this is where I am stuck/confused. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: To be brief, I am stumped on the summation expression you've left after step 5. It contains the sums of all the elements needed to generate $(a)$ so these elements are enough to give an ideal.

Comment: @Ryan: Every element of the form as in my last formula must lie in $(a)$. The question is whether these are *all* the elements of $(a)$. That is: is the set of all such elements (i) a subgroup of $(R,+)$ such that (ii) for every $x\in R$, if $m$ is of the given form, will $xm$ be in the set of all such elements; and (iii) for every $y\in R$, if $m$ is of the given form, with $my$ be of the given form. That is: the elements listed *must* be in $(a)$, but we haven’t checked that this collection of elements actually forms an ideal. It needs to be checked.

Comment: And when you “accept” the answer (as you have done), you are (i) signalling that you understand the answer; and (ii) that there are no further questions. This discourages people from giving you alternative answers/solutions. You should **never** accept an answer you are confused about! You should un-accept this answer, given that, by your own admission, you don’t get it yet.